# Force float3 to migrate toward 0.0 or 1.0

Tags: math, hlsl

I have a shader for normal mapping that takes into account light direction, and I'd like to intensify the effect. This is the line used to calculate the brightness of any given pixel of the model:

```
float3 N = (2.0 * (tex2D(NormalMapSampler, Tex))) - 1.0;
```

It forces the value to stay between 0 and 1, which is what I want. However, I would like to increase values above 0.5 and decrease values below 0.5 without using rounding, in order to have a more dramatic difference between the side of the model that is facing the light source and the side of the model that isn't. What can I use to achieve that?

Comment: Isn't N supposed to give you the normal? not the light amount (which you get using dot product in case of basic light equation). To increase contrast you can simply use pow(lightcontrib,power) * scale which would allow you to tweak (be wary of negative values of course).

Answer (score 0):

The formula produces vectors with values between -1 and 1. I don't think that what you want makes much sense, but you could just increase the z-coordinate:

```
float3 N = (2.0 * (tex2D(NormalMapSampler, Tex))) - 1.0;
N.z *= 2; //or any other value
N = normalize(N);
```

The higher the factor, the less influential the normal mapping. It increases for values between 0 and 1.